# How do I specify children only in the Backbone.js event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a view which has a view inside it (the same view in fact, its recursive). I want only the internal view to handle the event from an 'a' onclick event. I tried to do this by specifying only the direct children in the selector, but it doesnt work.

iv tried:

```
events: { 
    'click >a': 'toggle'
},
```

and

```
events: { 
    'click > a': 'toggle'
},
```

but they dont work, any suggestions? (Note: doing things like using tags and classes wont work because the view is recursive (meaning that both the inner and outer have the same event definitions)

Comment: Could you show your full view and how you're instantiating it? In Backbone, the jQuery selectors are automatically scoped to the view element, it should work in theory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have run into the same issue, and have solved it by stopping the propagation of the event in my child view. For example...

```
events: {
    'click a': 'toggle'
},

toggle: function (e) {

    // Stop event here.
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    // Do more stuff...

}
```

This does not answer your question of how to specify specific child selectors, but it keeps the event from propagating up to other handlers.

Answer (score 1):

`e.stopImmediatePropagation()` is handy if you have no other events firing when you click that specific element. What you should do otherwise is compare the `e.currentTarget` with the element you want to select. I.e.

```
events: {
    'click a': 'toggle'
}

toggle: function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget == this.$el.find('a')[0]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That way, if you have a parent view also firing an event when that link is clicked, it won't be stopped by `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify the starting selector...meaning I'm not sure the base selector is assumed.

```
events: {
    'click #parent > a': 'toggle'
}
```

Haven't tried this, but it may work.

Comment: good to know, I would imagine this is probably related to their parsing of events.

Comment: ohh, could it be that the event is generated in the child view, but passed up to the parent? How do I filter this out?